# How do you show the exact number of asterisk on the textfield to the numbers pressed and not add an additional asterisk when enter is pressed?

Tags: java, swing, awt

My problem now is how do you show the exact number of asterisk on the textfield to how many numbers were pressed and not add an additional asterisk? Because it keeps on adding another asterisk on the textfield whenever I press the enter button. I have been trying where and what should I put to avoid adding an additional asterisk whenever I press the enter button

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Pincode extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
JLabel display, displayExtra;
JButton numButton;
JButton clr;
JButton etr;
String displayContent = "";
String[] numPadContent = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "CLEAR", "0", "ENTER"};
ArrayList<JButton> buttonList;
String PINCODE = "061904";
JFrame f;
Pincode(Container pane) {
    pane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(320, 335));
    display = new JLabel(displayContent);
    displayExtra = new JLabel(displayContent);
    display.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(320, 30));
    display.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLoweredBevelBorder());
    pane.add(display, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    buttonList = new ArrayList<JButton>(12);
    JPanel numberPanel = new JPanel();
    numberPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 3, 0, 0));
    numberPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(320, 260));
    for (int i = 0; i < numPadContent.length; i++) {
        numButton = new JButton(numPadContent[i]);
        buttonList.add(numButton);
    }
    for (int n = 0; n < buttonList.size(); n++) {
        buttonList.get(n).addActionListener(this);
        numberPanel.add(buttonList.get(n));
    }
    pane.add(numberPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
    clr = new JButton("Clear");
    clr.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(160, 30));
    clr.addActionListener(this);
    etr = new JButton("Enter");
    etr.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(160, 30));
    etr.addActionListener(this);
    pane.add(clr);
    pane.add(etr);
}
public void Authorized(){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f,"You are authorized");
}
public void Unauthorized(){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f,"You are not authorized!!!");
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String textThere = display.getText(), textThereExtra = displayExtra.getText();
    String additionalText = "";
    for (int a = 0; a < buttonList.size(); a++) {
        if (e.getSource().equals(buttonList.get(a)) && a!=11 && a!=9) {
            additionalText = buttonList.get(a).getText();
        }
    }
    int flag = 0;
    if (e.getSource().equals(buttonList.get(9))) {
        textThere = "";
        textThereExtra = "";
        flag = 1;
    }
    if(flag!=1) {
        display.setText(textThere.concat("*"));
        displayExtra.setText(textThereExtra.concat(additionalText));
    }
    else
    {
        display.setText(textThere);
        displayExtra.setText(textThereExtra);
    }

    if (e.getSource().equals(buttonList.get(11))) {
        System.out.println(textThereExtra);
        System.out.println(textThere);
        if(textThereExtra.equals(PINCODE)) {
            Authorized();
        }
        else {
            Unauthorized();
        }
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(new Pincode(frame));
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Please help me with my code. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not going to make is of anonymous classes for each button, then you should look at the `actionCommand` of the `ActionEvent`

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String textThere = display.getText(), textThereExtra = displayExtra.getText();
    String additionalText = "";

    if ("Enter".equalsIgnoreCase(e.getActionCommand())) {
        System.out.println(textThereExtra);
        System.out.println(textThere);
        if (textThereExtra.equals(PINCODE)) {
            Authorized();
        } else {
            Unauthorized();
        }
    } else if ("Clear".equalsIgnoreCase(e.getActionCommand())) {
        textThere = "";
        textThereExtra = "";
        display.setText("");
        displayExtra.setText("");
    } else {
        for (int a = 0; a < buttonList.size(); a++) {
            if (e.getSource().equals(buttonList.get(a)) && a != 11 && a != 9) {
                additionalText = buttonList.get(a).getText();
            }
        }
        display.setText(textThere.concat("*"));
        displayExtra.setText(textThereExtra.concat(additionalText));
    }
}
```

*nb: This is quick re-working of your code, which might not be 100% correct for your needs, but should be give you push in the right direction*